# Three.js: How to count the Objects Added in Scene

Tags: three.js, blender, scene

How do I access element by elements exported from a full scene .blend file!

In this test, I exported a Blender scene with four cubes. Now, with three.js, I want to store these cubes (objects) in a javascript Array. I tryed this:

```
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<script src="./js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/OBJLoader.js"></script>

<div id="render">
</div>

<script>
// VARIÁVEIS

var qtd = 0;
var tam = 0;
var Modelo;
var Elementos = [];

// OBJETOS
var Render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var Cenario = new THREE.Scene();
var Cam = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
var LuzDir;
var controles;

// modelo 3d com .ObjectLoader()
var Modelo3d_Object = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
Modelo3d_Object.load('modelo3d_teste.json', funcaoCarregaJSON);

// INI FUNCOES
inicio();
animacao();
console.log(Cenario);
console.log(Cenario.__webglObjects);
Elementos = Cenario.__webglObjects;
console.log(Elementos.length); 

// FUNÇÕES
function inicio(){
    Render.setSize(600,600);
    document.getElementById('render').appendChild(Render.domElement);
    Cam.position.z = 100;
    Cenario.add(Cam);
    Cenario.add(new THREE.GridHelper(100,10));
    LuzDir = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    LuzDir.position.set(100, 100, 50);
    Cenario.add(LuzDir);
    controles = new THREE.OrbitControls(Cam, Render.domElement);    
}

// Carrega arquivo JSON
function funcaoCarregaJSON(geometry){
    geometry.position.x = 0;
    geometry.position.y = 0;
    geometry.position.z = 0;
    Cenario.add(geometry);
}

function animacao() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animacao);
    render_modelo();
}

function render_modelo(){
    // Renderizar
    Render.render(Cenario, Cam);
}    
</script>
<html>
```

But in this case I can see only one element.

[image: 1 or 4 elements in ".__webglObjects"?]

Where I went wrong??

[Download: .JSON File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCrDCNet1K3R2kzLVdvRXdFOXM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

In your `funcaoCarregaJSON()` just before you return I would do:

```
var numOfMeshes = 0;
geometry.traverse( function( child ) {
    if( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
        numOfMeshes++;
} );
```

Comment: Thank Gaitat , I tried this but it did not work. 
" numOfMeshes " as a global variable is not updated in _callback function.
I'm trying to figure out how to access my four cubes through _cenário . Can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You should count the scene children:

```
Cenario.children.length
```